# PyQt5 Example of Using `QSizePolicy` to Shrink a Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to stop a widget from expanding by setting its size policy but things are not working.

---

The following code runs:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        
        self.left_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.left_widget)
        
        self.right_widget = RightWidget()
        #self.right_widget.groupbox.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.right_widget)
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

class RightWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.groupbox = QGroupBox()
        self.groupbox.setTitle("some title")
        #self.groupbox.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.groupboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.button1 = QPushButton ("1")
        self.groupboxlayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.button2 = QPushButton ("2")
        self.groupboxlayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.button3 = QPushButton ("3")
        self.groupboxlayout.addWidget(self.button3)
        
        self.groupbox.setLayout(self.groupboxlayout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupbox)
        
        self.button4 = QPushButton ("4")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button4)
        
        self.button5 = QPushButton ("5")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button5)
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    system_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    system_app.exec()
```

It gives:

[image]

The specific choice of widgets should not matter. The point is that, there is a large widget on the left and there are smaller widgets on the right that is not large enough to fill the column. I want to modify the above code to shrink the widgets on the right hand side. That is:

[image]

In words, I want the widgets to shrink to top and bottom of the page in a way taking minimum  space (and hence leaving the middle empty).

---

I attempted to use `QSizePolicy` to achieve the desired result. The commented lines seem to have no impact on the page at all. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: 1. "The specific choice of widgets" ***does*** matter, since every widget can have its own size policy; 2. use `self.layout.addStretch()` *after* `self.layout.addWidget(self.groupbox)`; 3. read more about size management, including `sizeHint`, [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop), [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (and related classes, like [QLayoutItem](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html)), and don't forget to use Qt Designer to test and experiment with widgets and layouts.